Al usar una API con Python el request no me devuelve la respuesta completa
Al consultar una API veo que me recorta la respuesta completa y me pasa solo la mitad del ‘result’ y no llega al ‘records’. Si lanzo la consulta por un navegador sí veo los datos completos del JSON: ‘result’ y ‘records’
Qué más le faltaría a mi código ? Ya lo probé incluyendo al request un  headers con user-agent pero me da la misma respuesta incompleta.
La consulta es:

https://api.datosabiertos.mef.gob.pe/DatosAbiertos/v1/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%220b938fa8-f18c-4685-88ae-a9d7e392cafa%22%20WHERE%20%22SECTOR_NOMBRE%22%20LIKE%20%27GOBIERNOS%20REGIONALES%27%20LIMIT%2010

El código es
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://api.datosabiertos.mef.gob.pe/DatosAbiertos/v1/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * FROM \"0b938fa8-f18c-4685-88ae-a9d7e392cafa\" WHERE \"SECTOR_NOMBRE\" LIKE 'GOBIERNOS REGIONALES' LIMIT 10"
response = requests.get(url)  
data = response.json()
if 'result' in data and 'records' in data['result']:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['result']['records'])
        print (df)
    else:
        print("La respuesta de la API no tiene el formato esperado (falta 'result' o 'records')")


Saludos. Solo como observación... donde mencionas que te llega la mitad ‘récords’ tiene acento mientras que cuando refieres (al navegador) sí llega completo no tiene acento ‘records’ (así como en la parte de código que proporcionas no tiene).

Hola, al menos en mi caso tu código entra siempre en el else (corregido el error de identación antes). data['result']['records'] no existe, las claves de data['result'] son  'sql',  'records_format' y 'limit'. En todo caso sería data['records'] que contiene una lista con los datos. En mi caso el JSON es el mismo vía requests que el proporcionado por el navegador.

Gracias FJSevilla. Tu respuesta me ha dado pistas para revisar. Lo he ejecutado en Google Colab y efectivamente se puede leer el número de registros que se le requieran. Pero donde necesito ejecutar el programa es en VS Code, aquí es donde se corta la respuesta, cuando le pido 5 registros funciona pero de 10 a más registros se corta la respuesta y sale el consecuente error al cargar el JSON en Pandas. Voy a actualizar la consulta y el programa que funciona ok en Collab para centrar el problema en VS Code.
